# How to access each line in for loop and split string

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I want to read text file and write csv: 
I use the following code,

```
import glob
import os
import re
list_of_files=glob.glob('D:\Mekala_Backupdata\PythonCodes/textFile.txt')
for fileName in list_of_files:
    fin=open(fileName,"r")
    data_list=fin.readlines()
    fin.close()
    targetSubString='-------'
    indices=[idx for idx,s in enumerate(data_list) if targetSubString in s]
    reqData=data_list[indices[0]+1:indices[1]]
    fout=open("stripD.csv","w")
    fout.writelines(reqData)
    fout.flush()
    fout.close
```

1. I want to split the string in each line, and save first column into para_list, column3 into end_Value
2. in end_values, I want to keep the first string (if number, or logical operator), or whole siring if it is text.

My desired output:

```
para_list:
parq
10Lqr
29Hyt
Zgeat1
Beget

end_values:
33.0 mm 
23.0
1.0
Noraml set
12
```

please any one help, many thanks in advance,

my text file is below:

```
File Name:thUIK003K

Version:002BA07Gh
Name:HUJKO


Parameter        Start        End
-------------------------------------
parq             56 mm        33.0 mm 
10Lqr            12.0 mm      23.0 mm
29Hyt            0.0 %        1.0 %
Zgeat1           normal set   noraml set
Beget            12 km        12 km
-------------------------------------
other events:
11000 vent trig
213455 alram

xpara  ypara
1      3
2      3
4      8
6      10
-------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
My environment is python3.5 and wiondows10.
```

```
import glob
import os
import re

list_of_files=glob.glob('E:/StackOverFlow/python/01/pythonCodes/*.txt')

for fileName in list_of_files:
    fin = open(fileName, "r")
    data_list = fin.readlines()
    fin.close()
    targetSubstring='-------'

    count = 0
    data_list2=[]
    line = data_list[0] 
    for line in data_list:
        if targetSubstring in line and count > 0 :
            break;

        if targetSubstring in line  or count > 0 :
            count=count+1
            data_list2.append(line)

    data_list2.pop(0)

    columns = []
    column1 = []
    column3 = []

    for line in data_list2 :
        columns = re.split('\s{2,}',line)
        column1.append(columns[0])
        column3.append(columns[2])

    #fout = open('stripD.csv',"w") 
    path,ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fileName))
    fout = open(path +'_' + 'stripD.csv',"w")

    fout.write('para_list:\n')
    for line in column1 :
        fout.write(line)
        fout.write('\n')

    fout.write('end_values:\n')

    for line in column3 :
        line_tmp = re.findall('[\d.]{2,}',line)
        print(line_tmp)
        if len(line_tmp) !=0 :
            fout.write(line_tmp[0].strip())
        else:
            fout.write(line.strip())

        fout.write('\n')

    fout.close()
```

```
input:#same contents
textFile.txt
textFile01.txt

result is below

output file name:textFile_stripD.csv
para_list:
parq
10Lqr
29Hyt
Zgeat1
Beget
end_values:
33.0
23.0
1.0
noraml set
12

output file name:textFile01_stripD.csv
para_list:
parq
10Lqr
29Hyt
Zgeat1
Beget
end_values:
33.0
23.0
1.0
noraml set
12
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But if I have multiple files, how read each text file one by one, and do the same thing, and append the data vertically.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake. I fixed it now. ;D

Comment: Sir, I want read all text files in the folder one by one, do the same thing as above on each file(iteration).

Comment: fixed it again. output the result file one by one. ;D

Comment: Sir, finally I want to filter my final data such as after parsing all variable, I want to filter the below variables and their corresponding end values as my final required data:
required parameter list:

paraListFinal:
parq
29Hyt
Beget

required end valueslues: 
end_valuesFinal:
33.0
1.0
12

Comment: Did you make it? if I were you, I use count value. if count is odd, append the line.:) Good luck.